# Spring boot pom.xml set up with assembly descriptors

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have created Spring boot application and now we want to deploy it to linux server.

Process is we create zip file of jar and then unzip it on server.

my pom.xml build set up is as follows:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>

                <mainClass>com.csg.fid.emg.xray.eureka.server.EurekaServer</mainClass>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For other applications which are not Spring boot application pom.xml build set up is as follows:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemblies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>../src/main/assembly/bin-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now i want to include descriptor tag in build configuration of Spring boot app, which is not supported in configuration section of Spring boot app.

How can this be achieved?

My bin-assembly.xml looks like this:

```
<assembly
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>bin</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../src/main/assembly/include</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Comment: Why? Just copy the jar and run that. Why make it more complex than that?

Comment: Yes thats one way. I was just thinking of aligning it with existing deployment scripts.

Comment: So basically you want to make it more complex, try to shoehorn Spring Boot and its class loading into your own assemblies with all the issues that come with that. Are you really sure that is a way you want to go down.